# Get ngModel reference's length

Tags: angular

```
      <input 
            type="text"  
            name="email"
            placeholder="Identifiant (Adresse e-mail)"
            [(ngModel)]="account.email" 
            #email="ngModel" 
            required
            pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
        />
        <div *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid && email.length > 0 " >Cette adresse email n'est pas valide.</div>
```

I have got `email`which is a reference to the input. I want to display the text if user `touch` the input AND the length of the input is > 0 but I cannot access the input length. It seems like email.length doesn't work.

How can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to check length for `account.email` or just `email`?

Comment: Just the input field. I want to check if input.length > 0 so the error message won't trigger if the input is empty.

Answer (score 2):

When you referer to input element it is correct to use `email.touched`, but if you want to check email length you should use it like this:

`email.value.length`

or:

`account.email.length`

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Do you know, by any chance, how to check if the input has focus? Thanks

Comment: `<input (blur)="onBlur()" (focus)="onFocus()">`

Comment: [EDITED] `<input (blur)="onBlur()" #email="ngModel" (focus)="onFocus(#email)">` this should work for you. If you want to check this on your HTML you can pass input reference as function parameter and use it as javascript element in your function.

Comment: Thanks it works with (focus)="onFocus(email) instead of (focus)="onFocus(#email) :)

Answer (score 0):

use maxlength, the error will show if the email exceed the size in this case 10 fro example:

```
<input 
        type="text"  
        name="email"
        maxlength="10"
        placeholder="Identifiant (Adresse e-mail)"
        [(ngModel)]="account.email" 
        #email="ngModel" 
        required
        pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
    />

<div *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid && email.errors.maxlength" >Cette adresse email n'est pas valide.</div>
```